# Angular async pipe with RXJS : How to update given object?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

Let's pretend I have a simple observable that returns the currently connect user.

In my template I just call the user to show his profile information.

```
public $user: Observable<User>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.$user = this.userService.get();
}
```

And my view :

```
<div *ngIf="$user | async as u">
     ...
     <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]='u.synchronized'></ion-toggle>
</div>
```

Display works very well, I did heard that using Angular's async pipe was better for **stability**, **readability** and **performance**.

What is the best way to `this.userService.set(user: User);`? I changed some info in my user profile, but **what is the best pratice to update it through the API**?

Answer (score 0):

```
refreshUser(user) {
  this.userService.set(user: User).subscribe(() => this.$user = this.userService.get());
}
```

Call your setter, then refresh the observable by providing it a new value.

If the observable is **hot** and updated automatically, you don't have to do anything.

May I add that if you don't use hot observables and non-primitive types, the observables are useless, since Angular relies on memory reference changes to update the view, meaning that just setting the user would be enough.

Comment: Thank you. My observable is cold, this is an HTTP request. `since Angular relies on memory reference changes to update the view, meaning that just setting the user would be enough.` : can you explain that? 
What is I want to update my user during `ngOnDestroy`?